# True parallelism in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, gil

Is it possible to have true parallelism in python due to the presence of GIL? As far as I know each thread acquires the GIL before executing while other threads wait until the GIL is released. Why have GIL if it is such a bottleneck

Comment: See [David Beazley's GIL research](http://www.dabeaz.com/GIL/) for lots of great info on this subject.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python, the language does not necessarily enforce GIL. It's the different implementations of the language which may or may not have GIL.

CPython (the de-facto implementation) has GIL. So you can not have truly parallel threads while you're using it. However, you can use multi processing to gain parallelism. PyPy, another implementation of the language also has GIL now.

There are other implementations of the Python language (Jython & IronPython for example) which do not have GIL and you can use threads to run parallel operations.

Cython has a GIL but you can release it using a `with` statement.

Links of the projects mentioned:

- http://www.jython.org/
- http://ironpython.net/
- http://pypy.org/
- http://cython.org/

More resources on this topic:

- A question on programming stack exchange: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/186889/why-was-python-written-with-the-gil (Thanks to @Rogalski)
- Python Wiki: https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock
- David Beazley's talk - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Obt-vMVdM8s
- Article from Jeff Knupp : https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/06/30/pythons-hardest-problem-revisited/

Comment: Why cpython decided to use GIL. What benefit it go from GIL

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/186889/why-was-python-written-with-the-gil

Comment: @FaizHalde: there are hundreds of articles about the topic on the web

Comment: Better interoperability with C code. For example look at the plethora of the popular libraries - numpy, scipy, pandas - they all have a significant portion of the codes written in C.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn about the GIL in python, I'd suggest to start reading here:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

See the section *Eliminating the GIL* for an explanation why python still has the GIL.

Comment: BTW: you'll find that information by googling "python gil" and clicking on the first result... Might have been faster than posting on SO... ;)