# Is there a way to execute a file as a Thread using the threading module in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

so I was wondering if it is possible to execute a file (wheather .py, .java or any other extensions) and display the output in the console.

Let's say that I have a **main.py** file and an **file.java**. Now if I would run the main.py, it would return `You just runned the python file!` in the console, and if I run the file.java file, it would return `You just runned the Java file!`

Now is it possible to create a third file, and usind the [Threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) module, execute both of the files at the same time and display the outputs live in the console of the new file?

I am sorry if this is a little weird. Thanks!

Comment: It *sounds* like you just want to execute a couple of subprocesses. Yous hould use the `subprocess` module. Since it sounds like you want the calls in your main module to be non-blocking, you should use the `subprocess.Popen` constructor directly, which is a slightly more advanced use-case (for blocking calls, `subprocess.run` is adequate)

Comment: Right.  If you do `subprocess.Popen(['ls','-l'])` twice in a row, it will start both of them (almost) simultaneously and the output will be interleaved on your console, while your program continues on to the next thing.  (If on Windows, use `...['dir','/s']`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in these answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207309/how-to-run-functions-in-parallel), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38374629/true-parallelism-in-python)), CPython's GIL is unlikely to allow true parallelism with threading (which is useful for concurrency). The `multiprocessing` module is likely more effective for this, or alternatively using thread pools with a version of Python that does not implement the GIL such as JPython. Hope this helps.

Here is an example using the `multiprocessing` module paracoded from [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207309/how-to-run-functions-in-parallel), authored by user @NPE:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time


def f1():
    print("f1: starting")
    time.sleep(100)
    print("f1: finishing")


def f2():
    print("func2: starting")
    time.sleep(100)
    print("func2: finishing")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = Process(target=f1)
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=f2)
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Comment: Could you maybe give me an example with the module? Thanks!

Comment: Just updated the answer to include an example. This is almost exactly the same as the example given in the answer I linked you to.

Comment: this doesn't really address the OP's question. You are basically showing them how to execute a python function in a subprocess, not an arbitrary subprocess.